# Script to move a specific modifier (eg. Array) of two or more objects to top of Modifier stack

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers

Currently I have this script.(IMAGE) but also attached the blend file for better understanding [image]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/fjg3ger7lbukmlk/Text_s.py/file

https://www.mediafire.com/file/lr8yc0cttw3nkgh/test.blend/file

So what My code basically is doing for a selected object is as follows:-
finding if object has Mirror modifier or not.
If exists, I delete the already existing [Mirror] Modifier and make a new modifier Mirror with but with some pre-defined changes of its options:- like in my code, changing UV offset X to 1.0 from 0.0

My code works fine If I select just a object and run the script, but as soon as I select two objects. It gets frozen and eventually crashes.

I know this code description is too complicated. Don't mind it.
For now I basically want to develop a code as follows:

If I select two or more objects in scene and when I run the script.
my modifier[eg mirror] moves to top of modifier stack for both the objects.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Actually I did uploaded a image of code here, but it somehow didnt uploaded to post.

Comment: Also don't post images of code. If the code is relevant to the question post it as plain text using proper code tags, so people don't have to type it by hand.

Comment: [WiP... A comprehensive list of operator overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/60486)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As by this Q&A: [reorder modifier/constraints stack order in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39500/60486)

Use `bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up` or `..._down`. To avoid the need to make each object active before moving modifiers, use context override `{'object': ...}`

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C


def check(obj, name):
    index = obj.modifiers.find(name)
    if index == -1:
        raise KeyError(f"Couldn't find '{name}' modifier inside '{obj.name}' object")
    return index
        
def move_up(obj, name):
    check(obj, name)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up({'object': obj}, modifier=name)
    

def move_down(obj, name):
    check(obj, name)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down({'object': obj}, modifier=name)
    
    
def move_top(obj, name):
    for i in range(check(obj, name)):
        move_up(obj, name)
        
        
def move_bottom(obj, name):
    for i in range(check(obj, name), len(obj.modifiers)-1):
        move_down(obj, name)


for o in C.selected_objects:
    move_top(o, 'Mirror')
```

[image]

Comment: [How to move modifiers of multiple objects up or down?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175778/how-to-move-modifiers-of-multiple-objects-up-or-down)

Comment: Thank you, Markus von Broady , That's exactly what I needed!